# Can't set multiple types in interface proeprty using typescript

Tags: typescript

I started to learn typescript and I have this issue:

```
interface IActionSetId {
    id: string | undefined;
}

interface IActionSetIds {
    ids: string[] | undefined;
}

interface IAction {
    type: string;
    payload: IActionSetId | IActionSetIds;
}
```

I want to avoid using `any`.
Then I use it in this function:

```
function contextReducer(state: IState, action: IAction) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'setId':
            state.id = action.payload.id; // error
            break;
        case 'setIds':
            state.ids = action.payload.ids; // error
            break;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`);
    }

    return state;
}
```

When I try to access `action.payload.id` I get error:

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IActionSetId | IActionSetIds'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IActionSetIds'.
```

If I set one type on payload it works but I need payload to support many types.
I don't want to set any on this property as I want them to be stringly typed but I don't understand why I can't set multiple types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `switch` case cannot narrow between the two action. In both cases they could be both `IActionSetId` or `IActionSetIds`.

```
type IAction = {
    type: 'setId'
    payload: IActionSetId
} | {
    type: 'setIds'
    payload: IActionSetIds
}
```

Now you have a discriminated union.

Comment: Thanks. Is this better practice than ‘any’ type?